# Can we assign value of an element to ngmodel using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

This is my sample Javascript and angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.set="somevalue";
}
//javascript code
function addValueUsingJavascript() {
 var asdf=document.getElementById("1");
asdf.value="setttingvalue";
}
```

and here it

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input id="1" ng-value="set" ng-model="set">
<button id="forJq"  ng-click="ngFn()">Try me!</button>
</div>
```

I just want to set ngmodel value using `document.getElementById` only with  pure Javascript code... can we do this?

Comment: Explain what you expect? What should change? scope value? input value? should validation run? should input become dirty? etc.

Comment: scope value should be changed to the value which i gave through javascript

Comment: I think since you're changing things that angular won't know about - you're outta luck - I tried playing around a bit here: http://jsbin.com/wajecoraqi/edit?html,js,console,output but no dice. You could poll for changes maybe? Otherwise I'd just change the code to use angular to make the change to the `ng-model`

Comment: External APIs are best integrated into the AngularJS framework with services providers or directives. Look at [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for integrating with the `ng-model` directive. Look at [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for integration with the AngularJS framework model and its digest cycle.

Comment: thanks but is their anyway to do only with javascript(someother way)?